# How to focus radio button?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to focus in radio button used grouping in grid view. Now I write some code that is:

```
error = ((RadioButton)gridview1.rows[3].FindControl("radio1")).ClientID;
RunScriptBottom("DoFocus()","DoFocus");
```

That code is called in a JavaScript function

```
function DoFocus(){
    document.getElementById("<%=error%>").focus();
}
```

But that code has a JavaScript error. How should i do this?

Comment: whats the generated javascript code?

Comment: javascript Error - can not move focus to the control .Controls are not displayed,unavailable,or focus accept types

Comment: what does `RunScriptBottom` do? Insert the script at the bottom of the document?

Comment: protected void RunScriptBottom(string strScript,string strKey){ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),strKey,ScriptBuild(strScript));}

Comment: can you show us the resulting javascript?

Answer (score 0):

pass the id of the your error radio button to javascript function.
and from the javascript function you pick the id as variable and do focus.